# HTC ONE X: Rooting and boot loader

Tags: rooting, bootloader, htc-one-x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to root the new version of the ONE X](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32598/how-to-root-the-new-version-of-the-one-x)

How to root HTC ONE X from AT&T?

What exactly does rooting a phone mean?

What is the boot loader?

Is installing boot loader and rooting the same thing?

Comment: Duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/q/32598/7574 and http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/7574

Comment: If you don't know what means rooting a phone, I don't understand why are you asking **before** how to root your phone. I recommend you to carefully read about rooting: its advantages, its dangers, and then decide if you will do it or not.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rooting

Comment: And please check our [FAQ] -- only one question per post. Your question is 4 questions -- so do some math: 4 != 1, there must be something wrong :)

Comment: @Izzy : This has already been closed.

Comment: For understanding the Rooting check out the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_rooting and http://androidforums.com/nexus-7/615859-what-rooting.html.

Comment: The bootloader is the first thing that starts up when a phone is turned on. At its most basic level, a bootloader is the low-level software on your phone that keeps you from breaking it. It is used to check and verify the software running on your phone before it loads. Think of it like a security guard scanning all the code to make sure everything is in order. If you were to try to load software onto the phone that was not properly signed by the device vendor, the bootloader would detect that and refuse to install it on the device.

Comment: And installing/flashing the bootloader is not same as rooting. They both are separated process..

Comment: @KusH Yeah, same time as I wrote that comment. But please keep those facts in mind for future questions.

Comment: @avirk : seems installing bootloader is the initial required process for rooting a device

Comment: @FranciscoAlvarado : I am new with these android stuff, I am just trying to update my OS to jelly beans and I am trying to understand every methods, and trying to find the efficient and quick one

Answer (score 1):

[Root One X](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1952038).

[Official bootloader unlock](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1671396) and [unofficial unlock](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1672284).

Found all of these via Google. You can always search online for these kind of questions. And this question is likely to be closed down.

Comment: No these kind of question are not close now because every phone model may be differ way to root, and posting only links are not encouraged on SE sites you should add essential information from the links to here and give the links for reference.

Comment: @avirk Actually, this question is stil techincally a duplicate, so I voted to close.

Comment: @LiamW That is another case, I can understand why it is closed because I'm a part of SE and have a lot of knowledge how it works. I'm mostly activated on SuperUser and I have a kken interest in Android so I often come here to check but not regulary, I have also flagged it for the dupe.