# Rooting failed htc one x : adb server is out of date

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, rooting, adb, htc-one-x, att

Tried to root my mobile **HTC One X AT&T Build number 1.73.502.1 710RD ATT US edition** referring the following link.

[Root HTC One X](http://dottech.org/78439/how-to-root-att-htc-one-x-for-firmware-versions-1-73-and-1-82-guide/)

**Restarted twice but the phone was not rooted.**

```
    adb server is out of date.  killing...
    * daemon started successfully *
    ** daemon still not runningerror: cannot connect to daemon

    DON'T TOUCH THE DEVICE OR UNPLUG WHILE ROOTING!
    PUSH FILES
    adb server is out of date.  killing...
    * daemon started successfully *
    3388 KB/s (2005736 bytes in 0.578s)
    adb server is out of date.  killing...
    * daemon started successfully *
    2874 KB/s (91980 bytes in 0.031s)
    adb server is out of date.  killing...
    * daemon started successfully *
    3240 KB/s (570342 bytes in 0.171s)
    adb server is out of date.  killing...
    * daemon started successfully *
    adb server is out of date.  killing...
    * daemon started successfully *
    adb server is out of date.  killing...
    * daemon started successfully *
    adb server is out of date.  killing...
    * daemon started successfully *
    adb server is out of date.  killing...
    * daemon started successfully *

    REBOOT
    adb server is out of date.  killing...
    * daemon started successfully *
    ** daemon still not runningerror: cannot connect to daemon
    adb server is out of date.  killing...
    * daemon started successfully *
    adb server is out of date.  killing...
    ADB server didn't ACK
    * failed to start daemon *
    error:
    AGAIN REBOOT
    adb server is out of date.  killing...
    * daemon started successfully *
    adb server is out of date.  killing...
    * daemon started successfully *
```

Does rooting require bootloader ?

Comment: The bug is probably fixed in your build. Try bin4ry's 'root many android!' exploit http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1886460